# How to find the unique serial number of a flash device?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, removable-storage, removable

I've found several snippets and .pas files that can detect when USB flash drives are inserted and removed. Some give all kind of good information, however what I need is the devices' unique serial number, not the volumes' serial number.

My current .pas file (which I don't remember where I found) also seems to detect SD cards (which I like). If you want a look, you can find it here (it only returns the drive number and inserted/removed):

```
unit UsbDetector;

interface

uses Classes;

type
  TUsbDriveChanged = procedure (Sender: TObject; Drive: string; Attached: boolean) of object;

procedure StartUsbDetector(NotifyProc: TUsbDriveChanged);
procedure StopUsbDetector;

implementation

uses Windows, Messages, Forms, SysUtils;

type
  TUSBDetector = class(TObject)
  private
    fUsbDriveChanged: TUsbDriveChanged;
  protected
    procedure DeviceChanged(Msg: UINT; wParam, lParam: Longint);
    procedure DoUsbDriveChanged(Drive: string; Attached: Boolean); dynamic;
  public
    constructor Create(NotifyProc: TUsbDriveChanged);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property OnUsbDriveChanged: TUsbDriveChanged read fUsbDriveChanged;
  end;

var mUSBDetector: TUSBDetector;

procedure StartUsbDetector(NotifyProc: TUsbDriveChanged);
begin
  if not Assigned(mUsbDetector) then
    mUsbDetector := TUsbDetector.Create(NotifyProc);
end;

procedure StopUsbDetector;
begin
  FreeAndNil(mUsbDetector);
end;

{----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
// Device constants
const
  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL          =  $00008000;
  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE   =  $00008004;
  DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME          =  $00000002;

// Device structs
type
  _DEV_BROADCAST_HDR         =  packed record
     dbch_size:              DWORD;
     dbch_devicetype:        DWORD;
     dbch_reserved:          DWORD;
  end;
  DEV_BROADCAST_HDR          =  _DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
  TDevBroadcastHeader        =  DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
  PDevBroadcastHeader        =  ^TDevBroadcastHeader;

type
  _DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME      =  packed record
     dbch_size:              DWORD;
     dbch_devicetype:        DWORD;
     dbch_reserved:          DWORD;
     dbcv_unitmask:          DWORD;
     dbcv_flags:             WORD;
  end;
  DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME       =  _DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME;
  TDevBroadcastVolume        =  DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME;
  PDevBroadcastVolume        =  ^TDevBroadcastVolume;

var
  fPrevWndProc: TFNWndProc = nil;

function UsbWndProc(hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam, lParam: Longint): Longint; stdcall;
begin
  Result := CallWindowProc(fPrevWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
  if (Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE) and (mUsbDetector <> nil) then
    mUsbDetector.DeviceChanged(Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;

constructor TUSBDetector.Create(NotifyProc: TUsbDriveChanged);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fUsbDriveChanged := NotifyProc;
  if not Assigned(fPrevWndProc) then 
  begin
    fPrevWndProc := TFNWndProc(GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC));
    SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(@UsbWndProc));
  end;
end;

destructor TUSBDetector.Destroy;
begin
  //SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, LongInt(@fPrevWndProc));
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TUSBDetector.DeviceChanged(Msg: UINT; wParam, lParam: LongInt);
var
  lpdbhHeader: PDevBroadcastHeader;
  lpdbvData: PDevBroadcastVolume;
  dwIndex: Integer;
  lpszDrive: string;
begin
  // Get the device notification header
  lpdbhHeader := PDevBroadcastHeader(lParam);
  // Handle the message
  lpszDrive := '';
  case WParam of
    DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:    {a USB drive was connected}
    begin
      if lpdbhHeader^.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then
      begin
        lpdbvData := PDevBroadcastVolume(lParam);
        for dwIndex := 0 to 25 do
        begin
          if (lpdbvData^.dbcv_unitmask shr dwIndex) = 1 then
          begin
            lpszDrive := lpszDrive + Chr(65 + dwIndex) + ':\';
            break;
          end;
        end;
        DoUsbDriveChanged(lpszDrive, True);
      end;
    end;
    DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:    {a USB drive was removed}
    begin
      if lpdbhHeader^.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then
      begin
        lpdbvData := PDevBroadcastVolume(lParam);
        for dwIndex := 0 to 25 do
        begin
          if (lpdbvData^.dbcv_unitmask shr dwIndex) = 1 then
          begin
            lpszDrive := lpszDrive + Chr(65 + dwIndex) + ':\';
            break;
          end;
        end;
        DoUsbDriveChanged(lpszDrive, False);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TUSBDetector.DoUsbDriveChanged(Drive: string; Attached: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(fUsbDriveChanged) then
    fUsbDriveChanged(Self, Drive, Attached);
end;

end.
```

P.S. The code highlight is fail.

All in all;
When a removable is inserted/removed, get drive letter and its unique serial number. Maybe combine the already given code with a WMI call "where Index=found_index".

****EDIT!****
I removed the "where" clause in the code given by RRUZ. I finally found out how to handle the arrays, so I use that to find Capabilities[i]=7 to get all removable media. Now I just need to connect this code with the above code. I am thinking using Index, but I don't know how to use GetDrive MapInfo. If you could provide me with an example on getting the drive letter, my question is solved.

Comment: @Daniel, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687239/getting-connected-usb-info-with-delphi-on-vista

Comment: I did, but I forgot to tell I was hoping for a standard way (if such exists). I guess I can use this if there are no alternatives.

Comment: Alright, it works. But it only detects USB sticks. And there is no way I can connect that one with my already existing unit.

Comment: I found that I can use Capabilities[7] to get all removable drives (USB pens + SD cards, etc.), but I don't know how to use arrays in WMI queries. Furthermore, it'd be awesome if I could get the drive letter. There is an Index, but I can't find a GetDriveMapInfo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the WMI library by [Magenta Systems](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp) which takes most of the pain of using WMI queries.  The free download includes source and an example project that allows you to play with the API and queries to your hearts content.  You will want to keep a link to the official Microsoft [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(VS.85).aspx) which will help you with what query to execute to get what information...your interested in querying the classes using SQL like syntax queries.

For example, executing the query

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive Where InterfaceType = 'USB'
```

returns a wealth of information about all of the USB devices currently connected to the machine.  You can then use the PNPDeviceID as a unique identifier.

**EDIT** checking the only USB device I had handy returned a hardware serial number of "u" but a very long and valid looking PNPDeviceID which appeared to include a serial number, which is why I suggested that field.

**EDIT** You can get the drive letter by performing a query against `Win32_LogicalDisk` you can also query `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` which contains a mapping between `Win32_DiskDrive` and `Win32_DiskPartition`. Finally `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition` then maps a logical disk to a partition which in turn gives you the ability to link a physical USB drive to a specific drive letter.

Comment: Yes, it's something along those lines, but I'd like you to take a look at the comments to the question; I want all kind of removable devices (which includes SD cards). Furthermore, it should be possible to get this information when such device is inserted (and removed), maybe combine it with the code in the question?

Comment: you don't have to add anything in the where clause and it will return a record for ALL disk drive devices connected to the machine.

Comment: I know. That's what I am doing. But all I need is the drive letter.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the edit. Should I worry that there might be more than one partition on a USB drive?

Comment: Most likely not, but the OS does support it, so it is possible.

Comment: Sorry for awakening old thread, but...  Question: How safe actually is getting this serial number based on Win32_DiskDrive for licensing, aka can it be faked in some way? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure anything you do can be bypassed given enough time and resources.  The most perfect plan can be easily be thwarted by a clever hacker who modifies your exe directly and replaces your routine with a bunch of NOP instructions so it just skips over your critical check.  The best you can do is to make things somewhat difficult to bypass for the average person... trying to do much more wastes your time, and increases the possibility of false positives from actual paying customers.