# How to access hardware properties of a connected USB device in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to access the hardware properties (e.g. the driver key) of the connected USB device. How to do that?

I am able to detect whether the USB device is connected to the port or not using the TComponentUSB class properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting connected USB info with Delphi on Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687239/getting-connected-usb-info-with-delphi-on-vista)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SetupAPI functions. Recently, I had to detect Topaz USB Signature pads for a specific project using Reported Bus Description key and I achieved that using SetupAPI.

Check MSDN for documentation and JediVCL has some setupapi.pas unit that should help you. Some functions are not included in this unit though.